# Algorithms behind auto-adjust of color in images

Tags: image, automation, colors, adjustment

How does Auto-Adjust in Images work ?

example : [image]
<sub>(source: [iphoneography.com](http://www.iphoneography.com/storage/AutoAdjust_2_011109.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1257078828944))</sub>

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: @Chris O : I edited.. and posted an example :)

Comment: Looks like Histogram Stretch, rather Equalization, you are maximizing the contrast on all channels equally.

Comment: What do you mean by auto-adjust? Auto-adjusting of the color?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan : YES !

Comment: Naive answer - compute average brightness of the image, take in the desired average brightness, and then adjust each pixel. For computer-vision purposes I would compute the average brightness as ab = sum ((r^2+g^2+b^2)/(255^2*3)), and I would adjust (using db = desired brightness) as: r* = r * db / ab, g* = g * db / ab, b* = b * db / ab for every (r,g,b) in the image. However, human perception differs from the way web cam works, so there might be a better formula.